# WPF Component Styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm just starting studying WPF and a have this project to do.

I wrote this at the App Resources (app.xaml), don't know if this is the right thing to do to set the design of the components, but I thought it was pratical.

But when I started the program this happened [thats the program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MPc4.png)

Do I have how to fix this, or I have to declarate the styles on the XAML os the screen?

Thanks a Lot! 
Sorry about the English if there is any type mistakes

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="210" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="210" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="600" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="400" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: See all those crazy hard set Margins you have set on every instances? Those are your culprit. You're going to need to work on proper layout techniques or match your design window size to your actual window size but that wouldn't be suggested. If you want to share your full xaml I can show you how to recreate what you have to behave how you expect on any size later when I have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, Chris W called it with his comment advising you to look at the overall layout of your page first. Unfortunately, I cannot see what you have the height and width for the page itself set at, but it looks like the default is much smaller than the screen.

So, first - let's address the overall layout of the page before looking at any of the styling. I'm going to use a Grid and some StackPanels (I am typing straight into this answer, but hopefully I am going to be close. Consider this the disclaimer lol)

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LoginLayout}" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Text="Login"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtLogin"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Text="Senha"/>
      <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassw"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Button x:Name="btnLogin" />
       <Button x:Name="btnExit" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

The Grid container, and the StackPanels handle the layout and positioning of the elements and will help start a bit more responsive layout (not perfect, but coding this on the fly so to speak right now).

As for the styles, you probably noticed the Grid having a style - it is my habit and I prefer it especially when I am dealing with much larger projects. So, lets take a swing at the styles...

```
<Style x:Key="LoginLayout" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="110"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
</Style>
```

The styles you already defined for the other items should work, but may need a bit of tweaking - here is the button one as an example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
</Style>
```

I know this isn't a perfected style, however most of the positioning of these items are being handled by the grid and stackpanels. There are several other ways you could lay this page out - but hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

Good luck!